# PHPstan does not like preg_match parameters

Tags: php, phpstan

PHPstan gives this error

> Parameter #4 $flags of function preg_match expects TFlags of 0|256|512|768, int given.

to this code

```
    function my_preg_match(
        string $pattern,
        string $subject,
        array &$matches = null,
        int $flags = 0,
        int $offset = 0): bool
    {
        $result = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, $flags, $offset);

        if ($result === 1) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($result === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        throw new Exception(preg_last_error_msg());
    }
```

The code works.

Pleas explain me the error and help me fixing it to satisfy PHPstan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the function's docblock to match `preg_match()`'s function signature.

```php
/**
* @param 0|256|512|768 $flags
*/
```

See:

- https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#literals-and-constants
- https://phpstan.org/r/ef4a3c3e-9c67-46da-bd78-b08ded691318